# ffprobe OCR of a subtitle stream

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, ocr, ffprobe, tesseract-ocr

I have some video files containing HDMV PGS subtitles, and I need to convert them to subrip (or other text subtitles). I know that I can ffmpeg demux the video file to extract `.sup` and on the fly convert it to VobSub, then `subtitleedit /convert` that to subrip with its own tesseract.

However, I'd like to use only ffprobe/ffmpeg, which I have previously compiled with libtesseract and all. I don't mind parsing raw tesseract output into subrip either, but I just need to get it.

I've tried e.g.:

`ffprobe -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.ocr.text -f lavfi -i "movie=pgs.mkv,ocr"`

Naturally, it tries to read the video stream instead of one of the subtitle streams. Aiming it at a `.sup` file or multi-sub `.mks` or `.sub/idx` files gets me `No video stream with index '-1' found` error, which is technically true, but...

is there a way to make ffprobe/ffmpeg OCR the actual *subtitles* instead of the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image-based subtitles are a hybrid media type, they contain video data but are designated as subtitles. Almost all ffmpeg code expects actual stream data to be of the type they are indicated as. So, ffmpeg (and ffmpeg only) has bespoke routines to ingest such subtitles.

Use

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:s=hd720 -i pgs.mkv -filter_complex "[0][1:s:0]overlay=format=yuv444:shortest=1,ocr,metadata=print:key=lavfi.ocr.text:file=subs.txt" -an -f null -`

Comment: As I understand, this renders the subtitles on top of a black background of a size `hd720` (I had to put `hd1080` since my source is `Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080`), and then OCRs the entire thing frame by frame, as I'm getting multiple reads of the same text.

That's... pretty horrible. Beyond slow. But works, so thanks for showing me the way and an interesting trick! Since this appears to be the only way to do it with ffmpeg, I guess I'll stick to Subtitle Edit and maybe raw Tesseract at some point.

PS I love your work.

Comment: Add mpdecimate after the ocr filter to strip duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a new way.

If you like, you can try out an upcoming addition to ffmpeg which provides the capability for processing subtitles in filter graphs. Currently available here:

https://github.com/ffstaging/FFmpeg/pull/18

It also includes a new graphicsub2text filter for subtitle OCR including text size, style and position, colors, outlines and alignment.